# How can I store cell ID information in Excel?

Tags: excel, openxml, epplus

Let's say I have a list of inventory items in a database

```
Apple    1
Pear     2
Orange   3
```

I want to write an XLSX file (I will be using OpenXML/EPPLus) so that the user sees something like:

```
-Fruit Name-
Apple
Pear
Orange
```

I plan on letting my user modify this file to write the file back to the database, so I would like to add to the cell the fruit's corresponding ID.  I know I could create an extra column and hide this, but I'm not a fan of hidden columns.  Is there a way of adding an attribute to a cell?

Comment: The cell already has a row attribute -- can you use that?  Would cause problems if the user inserts rows between others that are filled out, but that can be overcome by protecting the workbook, checking the item to prevent users from inserting rows.

Comment: How can I access the row/col attribute?  I'm not finding any methods in OpenXML/EPPLlus

Comment: In openXML, the cell would be contained in a parent row class, no?
`<row r="2" spans="2:12">
  <c r="C2" s="1">
    <f>PMT(B3/12,B4,-B5)</f>
    <v>672.68336574300008</v>
  </c> `... (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.row.aspx)

Comment: Thanks... It looks like EPPlus doesn't have access to those.  I might just go with hidden columns for now because it is an order of magnitude simplier